# Google Play console release to closed alpha instead of production

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have an app in Google play that is unpublished. It has a handful of test tracks and currently, I have users testing in Closed Alpha. However, I have added a release to Production with a timed/managed release which I have no intention of releasing as I have more testing to do and want to roll out a release to the closed Alpha track. But, from the looks of things in the if I review and publish I'm going to release the app to production/live which I'm not ready to do as yet. Is there a way to delete the Production release? Or will clicking review and publish allow me to select which track to publish?

[image]

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I also did the same. Please let me know too

Comment: Hey, no I couldn't find a way around it. Instead, we continued alpha/beta testing using Firebase App Distribution instead, which I preferred as there was more information about users onboarded with our testing.

Comment: Actually i want to publish to alpha track first then release to production  track. But there is no way to select alpha track to publish first then to production track. If i click publish it would publish to both tracks. I want to verify the app in alpha track first to verify it is working as expected. Not sure what would be best option in this case. I read that there is no way to delete the the release on production track, have to publish. Which sucks..

Comment: Yeah that's the issue I had, doesn't make sense for Play to work it this way!